# Can TFS build multiple solutions using "wildcards" or similar?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

If I want to build multiple solutions in TFS Build I can add multiple `SolutionToBuild` elements to the Build Definition.

However, I want to specify a path to a folder, and then have TFS automatically find and build all solutions in this folder and subfolder, without me adding a `SolutionToBuild` element for each individual solution.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but not with the default build template as is. In the early stages of build execution, find a suitable build process trigger and include a step that finds your solutions in a supplied directory, and enter these solutions in the list of the `SolutionToBuild` variable. Then your script will continue as if you have added multiple `SolutionToBuild` elements.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. You can open the build default template and see how the projects/solutions to build are built with MSBuild.